# Trouble with aura:if

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-iteration, aura-if

I am not sure why this is not working. I have an aura:if condition, if the check matches then the item should be displayed. Here in this code below I am checking the ofc.agentName is not empty then the item should be shown. Plz advise!

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! notequals(ofc.agentName, ' ')}">
   <li class="slds-p-left_xx-small slds-p-left_xxx-small">{! ofc.agentName }<Strong><i >Name Not Matched</i></Strong></li>
</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notequals(ofc.agentName, ' ')` compares the value to a single space character, `' '`. To check if the value is empty, use the [`empty()` function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm):

```
!empty(ofc.agentName)
```

This will evaluate to `true` if the value is anything other than `undefined`, `null`, the empty array, and the empty string. (Note that it *doesn't* check for strings composed only of whitespace, though).

Comment: +1,Propably `!!empty(ofc.agentName)` for negation!

Comment: Well, `"{! !empty() }"`

Comment: Agreed! OP was looking for negation so, just saying. Thanks

Comment: Right but I think one `!` is the use case here, no? He wants "not equal to blank" => `!empty()`

Comment: Or am I looking at it sideways again?